# Creating a function with variable number of inputs?

Tags: matlab, function, matlab-deployment

I am trying to define the following function in MATLAB:

```
file = @(var1,var2,var3,var4) ['var1=' num2str(var1) 'var2=' num2str(var2) 'var3=' num2str(var3) 'var4=' num2str(var4)'];
```

However, I want the function to expand as I add more parameters; if I wanted to add the variable `vark`, I want the function to be:

```
file = @(var1,var2,var3,var4,vark) ['var1=' num2str(var1) 'var2=' num2str(var2) 'var3=' num2str(var3) 'var4=' num2str(var4) 'vark=' num2str(vark)'];
```

Is there a systematic way to do this?

Comment: You don't intend to use the outputs with `eval` later, right...?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if they solved your problem. It's the check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fprintf`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) with [`varargin`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) for this:

```
f = @(varargin) fprintf('var%i= %i\n', [(1:numel(varargin));[varargin{:}]])
f(5,6,7,88)
var1= 5
var2= 6
var3= 7
var4= 88
```

The format I've used is: `'var%i= %i\n'`. This means it will first write `var` then `%i` says it should input an integer. Thereafter it should write `=` followed by a new number: `%i` and a newline `\n`.

It will choose the integer in odd positions for `var%i` and integers in the even positions for the actual number. Since the linear index in MATLAB goes column for column we place the vector `[1 2 3 4 5 ...]` on top, and the content of the variable in the second row.

By the way: If you actually want it on the format you specified in the question, skip the `\n`:

```
f = @(varargin) fprintf('var%i= %i', [(1:numel(varargin));[varargin{:}]])

f(6,12,3,15,5553)
var1= 6var2= 12var3= 3var4= 15var5= 5553
```

Also, you can [change the second `%i` to floats (`%f`), doubles (`%d`) etc.](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#input_argument_formatSpec)

If you want to use actual variable names `var1, var2, var3, ...` in your input then I can only say one thing: **Don't!** It's a horrible idea. Use cells, structs, or anything else than numbered variable names.

Just to be crytsal clear: Don't use the output from this in MATLAB in combination with `eval`! **`eval` is evil**. The Mathworks actually warns you about this in the official documentation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to accept a flexible number of input arguments, you need [`varargin`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html).

In case you want the final string to be composed of the names of your variables as in your workspace, I found no way, since you need `varargin` and then it looks impossible. But if you are fine with having `var1`, `var2` in your string, you can define this function and then use it:

```
function str = strgen(varargin)
str = '';
for ii = 1:numel(varargin);
    str = sprintf('%s var%d = %s', str, ii, num2str(varargin{ii}));
end
str = str(2:end); % to remove the initial blank space
```

It is also compatible with strings. Testing it:

```
% A = pi;
% B = 'Hello!';

strgen(A, B)

ans =

var1 = 3.1416 var2 = Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the function as many times as the number of parameters? I wrote this considering the specific form of the character string returned by your function where k is assumed to be the index of the 'kth' variable to be entered. Array var can be the list of your numeric parameters.

```
file=@(var,i)[strcat('var',num2str(i),'=') num2str(var) ];

var=[2,3,4,5];

str='';

for i=1:length(var);

str=strcat(str,file(var(i),i));

end
```